# intCounter, how to start at specific cell in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following basic Code for Counting from 1 to X (value in E1). This Code starts in A1.
Now I want the code  to start in e.g. A5, but when i change it, it just give me the total Value from E1 in A5.

```
Sub Counting()
Dim intCounter As Integer

Range("A1:A" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
    
    For intCounter = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("E1")
        Cells(intCounter, 1).Value = intCounter
        
    Next intCounter

End Sub
```

thanks,
Qncy

Comment: `Cells(intCounter + 4, 1).Value` or `Cells(intCounter, 1).offset(4).Value`

Comment: Great, works. Thanks a lot!